# Looking for a javascript that will force/redirect child page into iframe found in parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, iframe

im new here new in programming. I hope you can help me :)
I am using Iframe for a project. Ive read about Iframes and I know its not the best choice.
Unfortunately I cant find another replacement for it and make it work the way I wish.

**Here is my problem:**
I have an index.html page, which holds a main Iframe. I have external links on same server, e.g page1.html  page2.html page3.html.... what need is, prevent direct access to  e.g page1  through search engines and load page1 content into index.html iframe.

I came across many scripts, redirecting to index.html and load child page into Iframe, the issue is about its ugly url link in the browser. e.g 
""domainname/index.html?domainname/page1.html""

This bothers me because I need to access pages with simple url like e.g "domainname/page1" but if a user type it and click "go" it will convert to ""domainname/index.html?domainname/page1.html""

---

**I found another choice**, but I dont know how to implement it the way i need it, i.e access sub-domains  with simple slash (domainname/content) here it the link:

http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/using-jquery-load-content-page-without-iframe-536.html

Comment: "I am using Iframe for a project. Ive read about Iframes and I know its not the best choice." - there's almost always a better choice than iframes. I recommend asking another question about alternatives for your project.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/) file to instruct the search engine crawlers to ignore the pages?  Saves you a lot of trouble and lets you build the site without such contrivances.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out using robots.txt?  This could be used to prevent browsers to avoid pages you do not wish to appear in search results.

Comment: Yes I considered robot.txt. My real issue is about the url in address bar. Suppose someone want to see "mydomain/ryanstuff.html" I give them that url, but when they press "Go" this will transform the original url to something else.  

I was wondering if there's any possibility to redirect child page to main index page frame. Then pass some variable from child to index page, a script which will update and refresh the main iframe src. e.g

A variable in child page "var ifrm_url = page1.html"
then a script on the parent page that captures "ifrm_url" and pass this value to the Iframe.

Comment: Iframe is just a bad approach to what you were doing.  Look into URL rewriting and use that in conjunction with a robots.txt file.  You should reevaluate your options.